# use function that returns transformed data on grouped data in R

Tags: r, function, transform, grouping

I have a large dataset which contains multiple groupes. I have created a function that returns the data without any outliers. So if you have 100 observations it will fill the outliers with NA's, and return the 100 observations back)

I have a dataframe with two columns having the grouping variables (example male /female employed/unemployed). The third column will have the actual data that needs to have the outliers removed (example salary).

is there some function I can use that returns me a dataframe or matrix with the outliers removed per grouping variables.

something like:

```
data.without.outlier <- function.unknown(data, by=list(data[,"employment"],data[,"sex"]), FUN = (my outlier function))
```

All suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Anything you already tried? Or googled yourself? There are several very popular packages for grouped operations, like data.table and dplyr.

Comment: I usually use apply, or aggregate. However those functions only work for returning stuff like mean and standard deviatiin. I dont know how to use it to return a whole dataset in the format I want. I will look up dplyr and data.table and see if it will work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your "myoutlierfunction" returns a data frame, you can use dplyr like so:

```
library(dplyr)
data.without.outlier = data %>%
  group_by(employment, sex) %>%
  do(myoutlierfunction)
```